# LINQ fails when mocking IDbSet GetEnumerator

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, moq

I am trying to mock System.Data.Entity.IDbSet to make it return some data (in this case just an empty collection):

```
var mock = new Mock<IDbSet<Setting>>();
mock.Setup(x => x.GetEnumerator()).Returns(Enumerable.Empty<Setting>().GetEnumerator());
var myEnumerator = mock.Object.GetEnumerator();
var count = mock.Object.Count();
```

Here myEnumerator will have a non-null value, as expected, but mock.Object.Count() will throw an ArgumentNullException

```
System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: arguments
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.RequiresCanRead(Expression expression, String paramName)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateOneArgument(MethodBase method, ExpressionType nodeKind, Expression arg, ParameterInfo pi)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateArgumentTypes(MethodBase method, ExpressionType nodeKind, ref ReadOnlyCollection`1 arguments)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(Expression instance, MethodInfo method, IEnumerable`1 arguments)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Count(IQueryable`1 source)
```

If I replace IDbSet with an IEnumerable, it works as expected (count is zero). Why is IDbSet not mocked as I expect?

EDIT

It looks like LINQ tries to use the IQueryable interface, because this works:

```
var mock = new Mock<IDbSet<Setting>>();
var myQueryable = Enumerable.Empty<Setting>().AsQueryable();
mock.Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(myQueryable.Provider);
mock.Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(myQueryable.Expression);
mock.Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(myQueryable.GetEnumerator());
var count = mock.Object.Count();
```

Answer (score 5):

It turns out that LINQ has explicit implementations for IQueryable:

```
    public static int Count<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source) { 
        if (source == null)
            throw Error.ArgumentNull("source"); 
        return source.Provider.Execute<int>( 
            Expression.Call(
                null, 
                ((MethodInfo)MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()).MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TSource)),
                new Expression[] { source.Expression }
                ));
    }
```

Actually it makes good sense, how else would LINQ expressions translate expressions to Entity Framework queries.

So I have to mock the provider and expression as well:

```
var mock = new Mock<IDbSet<Setting>>();
var myQueryable = Enumerable.Empty<Setting>().AsQueryable();
mock.Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(myQueryable.Provider);
mock.Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(myQueryable.Expression);
mock.Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(myQueryable.GetEnumerator());
var count = mock.Object.Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
mock.Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(myQueryable.GetEnumerator())
```

to

```
mock.Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(myQueryable.GetEnumerator)
```